# Get a column info, based on the cell selected in view based table view (OSX)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

In a table view (view based (OSX)), is it possible to get the column name based on the the cell selected in the table view.

For example, If in a table view, I click on cell (row 3 col 5), does App UI kit framework or other, has a API that would give information on row/column of the cell clicked.

NOTE: I am aware of cell selection API (isSelected on the view) is already available, but it will not work when cell is in edit mode or if a cell is clicked and a cursor is blinking for edit in that cell. It only gives you boolean value whether or not cell is entirely selected but not the state/mode of cell in edit mode or clicked mode.

In a xib, I have a customised table view and two buttons. one for adding a row and other for searching. Now if i click "Add row" button a row is added to the table view with very first cell in edit mode (here i have used tableView editColumn:withEvent:selection API). Works good till here.

But, when i click search, i need to find which cell is currently selected and based on that perform some actions.

So could you please help me find a solution for it.

Comment: Why do you use UIKit when you explicitly say you are working a Cocoa application?

Comment: thats due to the frameworks I am using in my projects

Comment: Ask Google or Yahoo what UIKit is.

Answer (score 0):

NSTableView's `clickedRow` and `clickedColumn` properties will probably do the trick.

Comment: clikcedRow and clickedColumn works only when a cell click results in that particular cell selected. But when cell click action results in a cell editing, mouse down is not called and neither does clickedRow or clickedColumn. Hope your getting the point.